# Resources for learning Relativity

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

I´m looking for books to the study of Relativity.

I know that this is math stack schange and not physics stack schage, but I believe that some of the users here are interesed in physical-mathematical questions, and, i wanna ask for resources on this area, if it is posible, resources on Relativity that are more heavy in Math and soft in Physics.

Any suggestion (and the why of that suggestion) is acepted.

External links for this are too welcome.

Comment: What's your background?

Comment: Four calculus, two analysis, two topologies (sets and algebraic), two linear algebras, one course on differential geometry (but nothing in Riemannian Geo), and a little of complex variable. Sets, logic, probability and modern algebra too

Comment: Did you already study special relativity?

Comment: Yeah, but the basic ideas (complete understanding of say, high-school course) I haven´t study that at the University level, never.

Comment: What about electromagnetism and analytic mechanics?

Comment: Sorry, nothing of that. But, if it´s neccesary, i´m goin to study that.

Comment: Same question as in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125505/learning-general-relativity?rq=1

Comment: Check this question and the ones linked there https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3769113/532409

Answer (score 0):

This book was an amazing intro to  SR and had me giggling on the DC subway. It is the textbook for a grad school physics class in relativity.

https://smile.amazon.com/Introduction-Special-Relativity-Science-Publications/dp/0198539525/ref=sr_1_13?crid=854RBF322AWO&keywords=intro+to+relativity&qid=1566553080&s=gateway&sprefix=intro+relativ%2Caps%2C196&sr=8-13

After you eat that appetizer, the main meal is  The Road to Reality: A Complete Guide to the Laws of the Universe by Roger Penrose. Hawking was his comedy sidekick. Math heavy, but he teaches it to you. That's part of the fun.
https://smile.amazon.com/Road-Reality-Complete-Guide-Universe/dp/0679776311/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2Z1LISYU9SNXH&keywords=road+to+reality+by+roger+penrose&qid=1566553399&s=gateway&sprefix=road+reali%2Caps%2C208&sr=8-1