# Recommendation for a Differential Geometry/General Relativity text

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, book-recommendation, general-relativity

I'm an undergraduate Math student and I am doing a side project for which I would like to study Differential geometry and its applications in general relativity. I have taken a few proof based courses including Analysis I, Introductory Number theory, Abstract Algebra.

I would like to get a text that isn't too far above what I have studied but still challenging and informative. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a serious recommendation since I haven't taken a peek at the text yet, but I hear that advanced undergraduates sometimes use Wald's GR.

Comment: doCarmo's pretty great in the Differential/Riemannian Geometry sector

Comment: Winitzki has a book with *topics* on this material. While it's not comprehensive, it is freely available from the author.

Comment: This is worth looking at:
http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/physics/cosmology-relativity-and-gravitation/introduction-general-relativity-1

Comment: do Carmo's does not deal with lorentzian geometry, though... S Valera.

Comment: have you looked for other questions in this website? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125505/learning-general-relativity

Not claiming that yours is a duplicate, I am just pointing out that might be other related questions that you have missed.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295773/riemannian-geometry-book-to-complement-general-relativity-course

Answer (score 3):

Wald's General Relativity.

It is a book from a Physicist to Physicists, but any reader will not be missing statements and proofs (or sketch of them). His approach is still akin to formulations using coordinates, although he manages to do it in a global way.